# Divs with same height with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this structure of 8 divs aligned horizontally, and I want them to have the same height. Currently they have different heights depending on the content of the text inside them. Can anyone help?
I have tried many workarounds but it still doesn't work for me. I'm using bootstrap 3 so flex is not the solution :(

```
<div class="container" style="width:100%">
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-xs-3 clickable">
            <div style="color: #555555; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" style="text-align: center">Pending DTO</div>
                </div>   
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 clickable">
            <div style="color: #555555; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" style="text-align: center">Pending Offer</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 clickable">
            <div style="color: #555555; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" style="text-align: center">Pending Budget Approval</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 clickable">
            <div style="color: #555555; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" style="text-align: center">Pending Technical Analysis</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6" style="height:100%">
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-xs-3 clickable">
            <div style="color: #555555; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" style="text-align: center">Pending Information</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 clickable">
            <div style="color: #555555; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" style="text-align: center">Pending Provisioning</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 clickable">
            <div style="color: #555555; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" style="text-align: center">Pending in progress</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 clickable">
            <div style="color: #555555; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" style="text-align: center">Provisioned</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: What's the goal of having rows inside rows? Let me change you your structure a bit.

Comment: same height is easier with grid than with flex imo.

Answer (score 1):

I used bootstrap 3 only. This solution will help!!

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.equal, .equal > div[class*='col-'] {  
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex:1 1 auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row equal">
    <!--begin panel 1 -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div style="text-align:center" class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h1 class="panel-title text-center">Pending DTO</h1>
        </div>
        <!-- end panel-heading -->
        <div class="panel-body">
          
          <p class="text-left lead2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
         
        </div>
        <!-- end panel-body -->
      </div>
      <!-- end panel-primary -->
    </div>
    <!--end col-md-4 -->
    <!-- begin panel 2 -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div style="text-align:center" class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h1 class="panel-title">Gestíon de Redes Socials</h1>
        </div>
        <!-- end panel-heading -->
        <div class="panel-body">
         
          <p class="text-left lead2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
         
        </div>
        <!-- end panel-body -->
      </div>
      <!-- end panel-primary -->
    </div>
    <!-- end col-md-4 -->
    <!--begin panel 3 -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div style="text-align:center" class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h1 class="panel-title">Test</h1>
        </div>
        <!-- end panel-heading -->
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p> test
            
          </p>
         
        </div>
        <!-- end panel-body -->
      </div>
      <!-- end  panel-primary -->
    </div>
    <!-- end col-md-4 -->
  </div>
  <!-- end row -->
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: She specifically asked for 8 divs aligned horizontally having the exact same width. Your answer, and the OP's demands are completely different.

Comment: I found similar solutions that worked for me, we can add more divs to it https://www.codeply.com/go/bp/127827

Comment: As Islam says, I need specifically 8 divs, so your solution doesn't work for me :) but thanks anyway

Comment: I think this is a good answer. It is a simple working example of divs that are the same height with bootstrap. It's trivial to extend it to 8 divs.

Answer (score 0):

Each row need to have 12 columns, in your case you shouldn't put rows into each other :

```html
<div class="container" style="width:100%">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-3 clickable">
      <div style="color: #555555; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" style="text-align: center">Text example Text example Text example</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-3 clickable">
      <div style="color: #555555; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" style="text-align: center">Text example Text example Text example</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-3 clickable">
      <div style="color: #555555; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" style="text-align: center">Text example Text example Text example</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-3 clickable">
      <div style="color: #555555; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" style="text-align: center">Text example Text example Text example</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-3 clickable">
      <div style="color: #555555; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" style="text-align: center">Text example Text example Text example</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-3 clickable">
      <div style="color: #555555; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" style="text-align: center">Text example Text example Text example</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-3 clickable">
      <div style="color: #555555; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" style="text-align: center">Text example Text example Text example</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-3 clickable">
      <div style="color: #555555; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" style="text-align: center">Text example Text example Text example</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/he6na89r/

Comment: I need to have the 8 divs in the same row, so that's not an accurate answer for me :(

Comment: @Julia what's the goal? You have 12 columns, and a 1.5 column doesn't exist. So you'd need to add 1 and then 2 columns each time like so (https://jsfiddle.net/dtka6q9w/). But even then, if there's a lot of text it'll go to the next line. I'm not sure about what are you trying to do. But just remember, each row needs to have a maximum of 12 columns. Good luck!

Comment: I need this structure to match the mockup that designers have requested. The 8 divs should be side by side, that's what they have requested. I am able to align them but I need them to have the same height as the one which has most text, that's the thing I can achieve. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: I added an image on question to explain what I need to achieve